# Goog working regexp to get PHONE from HTML page

Tags: html, ruby, regex, web-scraping, phone-number

I try to get phone from HTML page, but I've tried many regexps and modules and it not work or error.
Example.

```
http://www.boat-duesseldorf.com/cgi-bin/md_boot/lib/pub/tt.cgi/Overview_Press.html?oid=58288&lang=2&ticket=g_u_e_s_t
```

You can see on page a lot of phones. +49 (0)211 4560-518 for instance.
And I find good regexp from Regexp base, Google recomend it.

```
http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2054
```

There is a lot of text so I wont past it here. Only regexp. Regexp should get a lof of phones formats.

```
^(\+\d{2}[ \-]{0,1}){0,1}(((\({0,1}[ \-]{0,1})0{0,1}\){0,1}[2|3|7|8]{1}\){0,1}[ \-]*(\d{4}[ \-]{0,1}\d{4}))|(1[ \-]{0,1}(300|800|900|902)[ \-]{0,1}((\d{6})|(\d{3}[ \-]{0,1}\d{3})))|(13[ \-]{0,1}([\d \-]{5})|((\({0,1}[ \-]{0,1})0{0,1}\){0,1}4{1}[\d \-]{8,10})))$
```

So I get HTML page http://www.boat-duesseldorf.com/cgi-bin/md_boot/lib/pub/tt.cgi/Overview_Press.html?oid=58288&lang=2&ticket=g_u_e_s_t with Nokorigi and make:

```
/^(\+\d{2}[ \-]{0,1}){0,1}(((\({0,1}[ \-]{0,1})0{0,1}\){0,1}[2|3|7|8]{1}\){0,1}[ \-]*(\d{4}[ \-]{0,1}\d{4}))|(1[ \-]{0,1}(300|800|900|902)[ \-]{0,1}((\d{6})|(\d{3}[ \-]{0,1}\d{3})))|(13[ \-]{0,1}([\d \-]{5})|((\({0,1}[ \-]{0,1})0{0,1}\){0,1}4{1}[\d \-]{8,10})))$/.match.(@html)
```

and `pp Regexp.last_match` - but get NIL!!!!

I need good regexp, please recommend 100% working regexp or module.

Comment: Try to remove initial `^` and final `$` from your regex, and try again.

Comment: Umm please do not beg. If someone can help you they will.

Comment: I've tried remove ^ $ - doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but hope it helps:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

site = 'http://www.boat-duesseldorf.com/cgi-bin/md_boot/lib/pub/tt.cgi/Overview_Press.html?oid=58288&lang=2&ticket=g_u_e_s_t'
html = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(site))

phones = html.scan(/[^0-9](\+[0-9\(\)\- ]{2,})/)
puts phones
```

Output:

```
+49 (0)211 4560-518 
+49 (0)211 4560-87-518 
+49 (0)211 4560-589 
+49 (0)211 4560-87-589 
+49 (0)211 4560-990
+49 (0)211 4560-545
```

Comment: Results and very interesting.

https://www.airliquide.com/connected-innovation/rd
+02
+01
+02
+1 302 286 5400
+33 (0) 1 39 07 62 62
+33 (0)5 63 72 69 69
+33 (0) 1 40 96 99 00
+49 69 4011 201
+49 40 521000
+86 21 5800 5852
+82 2 3019 2578
+81 (0) 298 879 0050

https://www.airliquide.com/connected-innovation/scientific-partnerships-excellence
+02
+02
+02
https://www.airliquide.com/connected-innovation/rd-competences-and-expertises
+02
+02
+02

Comment: I think I will make check if phone not longer than 3 sybols I will not user, else will. Thank you for regexp @jpnkls

Comment: Yes, because it's too simple :) You can do that or change the pattern I have updated. Tested and works on 4 url you shared.